# Getting error while deploying ABP IO Project in Azure web apps

Tags: c#, abp

While deploying the Abp IO project to virtual directory, I am getting the 500.35 HTTP Error.

[image]

I tried deploying the project but facing issues. Please provide me step by step solution for rectifying this error.

Comment: That error means your application crashed on startup. Did you check the logs? We can't guess what's going on. Perhaps the application is trying to connect to a non-existent database? Read for the wrong folder? The wrong runtime was used?

Comment: Try to set your web app in a different pool.